# Complete route with source and get its materialised value

Tags: akka-stream, akka-http

There's a route that goes somewhat like this:

```
val route = 
  path("data") {
    get {
      val src: Source[ByteString, BoundedSourceQueue[ByteString]] = ???
      complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/octet-stream`, src))
    }
  }
```

How can I access materialised value of this source?

Comment: In order to get materialized value you will need to load everything in memory, which sounds dangerous, because of potential OOM. What problem you would like to solve?

Comment: What? Materialized value is available as soon as graph is started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prematerializing `src` should do the trick.

```scala
// will need an implicit ActorSystem/ActorMaterializer in scope
val baseSrc: Source[ByteString, BoundedSourceQueue[ByteString]] = ???
val (bsq, src) = baseSrc.preMaterialize()
// do stuff with bsq...
complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/octet-stream`, src))
```